# Update nested array list in mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

hello all i have a collection like this ` "_id" : ObjectId("55dabba974cd60712be24443"),

```
    "entityType" : "1",
    "entityCreatedDate" : "08/24/2015 12:07:20 PM",
    "nameIdentity" : [
            {
                    "givenNameOne" : "JOY",
                    "givenNameThree" : "BRAKEL",
                    "lastName" : "BRAKEL",
                    "createdDate" : "08/24/2015 12:07:20 PM",
                    "sourceId" : [
                            {
                                    "sourceId" : "55dabba974cd60712be24441"
                            }
                    ]
            },

    ],
```

`Here name identity is a list as well as sourceId. I am trying to update sourceId list in nameIdentityList if it matches the names. My java code is :`

```
Document sourceDocument=new Document("sourceId",sourceId);
mongoDatabase.getCollection("entity").updateOne(new Document("entityId", entityId).append("nameIdentity.givenNameOne","JOY"),
                                new Document("$push", new Document("nameIdentity.sourceId", sourceDocument)));
```

` But i am getting exception like java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: cannot use the part (nameIdentity of nameIdentity.sourceId) to traverse the element ({nameIdentity.

If my condition is satisfied i am expecting like this:

```
`"_id" : ObjectId("55dabba974cd60712be24443"),

        "entityType" : "1",
        "entityCreatedDate" : "08/24/2015 12:07:20 PM",
        "nameIdentity" : [
                {
                        "givenNameOne" : "JOY",
                        "givenNameThree" : "BRAKEL",
                        "lastName" : "BRAKEL",
                        "createdDate" : "08/24/2015 12:07:20 PM",
                        "sourceId" : [
                                {
                                        "sourceId" : "55dabba974cd60712be24441"
                                },
                                {
                                        "sourceId" : "55dabba974cd60712be24435"
                                }
                        ]
                },

        ],`
```

. any suggestions where am i going wrong?
I have multiple names in my nameIdentity, even if the matched document is second or third , sourceId is always being appened to first document. How do i update to specific matched document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the [positional `$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator after the "nameIdentity" field in `$push`:

```
Document sourceDocument=new Document("sourceId",sourceId);
mongoDatabase.getCollection("entity").updateOne(
  new Document("entityId", entityId).append("nameIdentity.givenNameOne","JOY"),
  new Document("$push", new Document("nameIdentity.$.sourceId", sourceDocument))
);
```

The `$push` action like other update action modifiers needs to know the "index" of the matched array element to work on. Otherwise the error as you reported occurs.

Comment: I have multiple names in my nameIdentity, even if the matched document is second or third , sourceId is always being appened to first document. How can i update matched document.

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli The positional `$` operator ( as also explained in the linked manual page ) does not return the matched index of anything but the "first" occurance of a match which always means the "outer" array. In this case you only need the "outer index" match, so that is fine. This will append to the matched index of whatever the query conditions for that array matched. In your case, whatever the name is. But if you had "JOY" more than once, then only the first is matched. However the question you asked did not use the positional `$` operator at all.